# How to identify whether browser is supporting angularjs or not?

Tags: angularjs, browser-support

I need to identify if a browser supports the AngularJS.

Based on the result, I need to execute logic to call web pages. Old browsers like IE6 and IE7 do not support AngularJS. So one way to identify if a browser supports it, is by detecting the browser **version/type**, but I am looking for a more generic way to check support.

Comment: There is no way but to manually check the browsers angularjs reported they do not support. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From angular's [FAQ page](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)

> What browsers does Angular work with? We run our extensive test suite
>   against the following browsers: Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE8,
>   IE9 and mobile browsers (Android, Chrome Mobile, iOS Safari). See
>   Internet Explorer Compatibility for more details in supporting legacy
>   IE browsers.

And the IE specifics cab be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

If you'r looking for a `angular.is_this_browser_supported()` function, i doubt you'll find any.